# Axios Interceptors and Try/Catch error handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, try-catch

In my React Native app, I handle each call to the api within a `try/catch` block and am also using `axios interceptors` to handle the errors that I get from the server.

The problem is that using both of them seems redundant since I'm already handling the errors with `axios interceptors` and have no need of the `catch` block. Yet removing the `try/catch` blocks result in an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

**`try/catch` for api calls: (*WILL REMOVE THE CONSOLE.LOG*)**

```
// Request to the server
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axis.post('API_URL',{BODY});
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**`axios interceptors`:**

```
// Intercept on response
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  res => {
    return res;
  },
  err => {
    // Error handling logic
    // ....................

    return Promise.reject(err);
  },
);
```

**Is there any way I can keep using `try/catch` in my functions and still handle the errors with `axios interceptors` or just use `axios interceptors` and avoid the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`?**

Answer (score 0):

You might have already figured this out, but I'll try to give some input.

If you do as you have `return Promise.reject(err)` then the `err` object will be sent to your `catch` method. If no `catch` is present the error will be thrown to the console.

If you instead just use `return err` or any other value, that value will be returned to the `then` or `await` method/variable.

Hope this helps.